# Как автоматизировать добавляемые данные в массив

Tags: php, javascript, html, массивы, автоматизация

Привет, с  столкнулся  с ситуацией, когда  нужно  добавлять очень много   данных в массив  вручную,  что стало отнимать уж очень много времени. Хотелось  бы  этот процесс автоматизировать,  я больше верстальщик и  мне  немного тяжело решить эту проблему.

Есть html документ с списком данных о клиентах у которых есть  свой  атрибут, вот код:

```
  <div class="content-wrap">
            <h3 class="middle-title">информация</h3>
            <p class="address" data-category="category1" data-num="0">информация</p>
            <p class="membership">информация</p>
            <div class="info-wrap">    
                <a href="tel:0542190175" class="contact-info phone">054-2190175</a>
                <a href="" class="contact-info mail" target="_blank"информация</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse-icon close"></div>
        </div>
```

А так  же js, в  котором  находятся данные  для google maps.
Получается,  что при клике  на блок на карте отображаются координаты и личная информация о клиенте.
 вот пример  кода:

```
      "category1":[
                {id:'1', latLng:[43.5847191,2.169831], address1: " Адрес, <br>Информация<br> <a href=\"tel:0563756518\">056-375-6518</a>", options:{icon: "images/marker.png"}},
                {id:'2', latLng:[43.5847191,2.169831], address1: "Адрес, <br>Информация<br> <a href=\"tel:0563756518\">056-375-6518</a>", options:{icon: "images/marker.png"}},
                {id:'3', latLng:[43.5847191,2.169831], address1: "Адрес, <br>Информация<br> <a href=\"tel:0563756518\">056-375-6518</a>", options:{icon: "images/marker.png"}}
]
```

ну и т.д.
Проблема  в том, что  собралась приличное количество данных, и менять их позиции местами и менять информацию  стало достаточно сложно и появилась необходимость автоматизации.
Буду  благодарен за развернутые ответы  опытных программистов куда мне копать)
Всем спасибо!

Comment: вы бы еще написали что вы хотите менять местами, где, и по какому принципу. а то написали, что сложно меня, а что и как почему то забыли, хотя в этом вся суть вопроса должна быть.

Comment: Я так понимаю, в этом массив данные попадают путем редактирования файла с кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Копать вам нужно в сторону баз данных, где этот процесс автоматизирован изначально. Вы зачем-то пытаетесь использовать для этого массивы в самом JS. Можно конечно и ложкой гвозди забивать, но значительно проще и быстрее использоваться более подходящий инструмент.